# Failed to locate: "CL.exe", Opencv with Visual studio c++ 2010 express program error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, build-error

I have tried a lot of tutorials regarding configuring opencv 2.2 or 2.3 with MVS 2010 express C++, I tried also uninstall and reinstall my MVS 2010 to sure that it is working. Moreover I also configured it with opencv, like creating property sheets (DEBUG & RELEASE) and then set the Additional dependencies, libraries,includes, etc.

But when trying to run a simple program (Like displayin a video), I get this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: wew, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file     specified.
1>  
1>  
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Has anybody experienced the same problem and solved it?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this while installing React Native via npm. I solved it by following the advice in this post: [Visual studio doesn't have cl.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953769/visual-studio-doesnt-have-cl-exe)

> Visual Studio 2015 doesn't install C++ by default. You have to rerun
>   the setup, select Modify and then check Programming Language -> C++

I assume it would work for older versions of Visual Studio as well.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error today and my problem was that I had accidentally overwritten the "executable directories" part of the project's property pages. I.e. I overwrote the (common properties->VC++ Directories->Executable directories) entry.