# Visual Studio 2015 doesn't have cl.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded Visual C++ and Visual Studio, but I  cannot find `cl.exe` to compile my C++ file. The path to the install is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin.

Where can I find the compiler to compile C++ code?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?  Did you do a full install?

Comment: The C++ compiler doesn't get installed if you choose the Express Install option. Reinstall and select the Custom Install this time.

Comment: Ok I will try to reinstall, thank you

Comment: I had this error when trying to install some package for node.js on Windows, I was getting a `node-gyp rebuild` error. So I installed Python, then reinstalled VS with C++ option checked, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 doesn't install C++ by default. You have to rerun the setup, select Modify and then check Programming Language -> C++

Comment: You know you can tick this on under 'Programming Languages' by choosing "Custom" when installing.

Comment: You don't need to re-download the installer for Visual Studio: just go to `Add or remove programs -> Visual studio community 2015 -> modify`. From there, I clicked `languages, Visual C++`. Added cl.exe!

Answer (score 8):

In Visual Studio 2019 you can find cl.exe inside

```
32-BIT : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\Hostx86\x86
64-BIT : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\Hostx64\x64
```

Before trying to compile either run vcvars32 for 32-Bit compilation or vcvars64 for 64-Bit.

```
32-BIT : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
64-BIT : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
```

If you can't find the file or the directory, try going to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC` and see if you can find a folder with a version number. If you can't, then you probably haven't installed C++ through the Visual Studio Installation yet.

Comment: *"Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"* is Visual Studio 2015. Also see [Microsoft Visual Studio | VS2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2015) on wikipedia.

Answer (score 6):

For me that have Visual Studio 2015 this works:
Search this in the start menu: `Developer Command Prompt for VS2015` and run the program in the search result.
You can now execute your command in it, for example: `cl /?`

Answer (score 0):

For first need check is installed **cl.exe**,
open Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 and type "where cl"
When its founded on the PC need add **$(VC_LibraryPath_x64)**, **$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64)** and **$(NETFXKitsDir)Lib\um\x64** to *Project->Properties->VC++ Directories*