# Visual studio compiler directory in windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, qt, compiler-construction, qt-creator

I have install Visual Studio Community 2015. I want to add the visual studio 2015 compiler to Qt Creator. So I get to this screen. https://snag.gy/QND9wl.jpg
Now it is asking me to provide the details for the compiler path and make path. When I go to D:\Visual Studio\VC\bin I cannnot find Cl.exe. What are the exact paths for the compiler?

Comment: what does the `auto-detected` show ?

Comment: Just the MinGW 5.3.0 32bit compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually install the C++ environment? By default, Visual Studio Community 2015 doesn't.

You should rerun the setup and make sure that “Visual C++” is checked under “Programming Languages”.

Possible duplicate: [Visual studio doesn't have cl.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953769/visual-studio-doesnt-have-cl-exe)

Comment: This is probably the problem, Qt Creator should auto-detect VS2015.