# Visual studio 2017 and the cl.exe error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to run the following command in Windows:

```
pip install flask-sqlalchemy mysql-python
```

But I get the following error:

```
cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG / MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) 
-D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" "-Ic:\users\mrnoname\anaconda3\include" "-Ic:
\users\mrnoname\anaconda3\include" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release/
_mysql.obj /Z1

error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
```

I looked up cl.exe error and found a thread on SO.

[Visual studio doesn't have cl.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953769/visual-studio-doesnt-have-cl-exe)

> Visual Studio 2015 doesn't install C++ by default. You have to rerun
>   the setup, select Modify and then check Programming Language -> C++

But for Visual Studio 2017, I don't see such an option. There is no "Programming Language" option to select C++.

I tried installing most of the C++ options (skipping only ones like designed specifically for gaming or other things irrelevant to me) but this didn't solve it.

Does anyone have suggestions for how to correct this for Visual Studio Community 2017?

Answer (score 1):

Did you miss this option in the Visual Studio 2017 Setup?

[image]