# Installing Python libraries for Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, windows, raspberry-pi, visual-studio-2017

I tried installing the Rpi.GPIO library on Visual Studio 2017 to have access to auto-completion in VS.
I got the following error :

> cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files\Python36\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python36\include" /Tcsource/py_gpio.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\source/py_gpio.obj
>      error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

I already done some research :
[Visual studio 2017 and the cl.exe error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162464/visual-studio-2017-and-the-cl-exe-error/43162872#43162872)
I have Visual C++ installed

Comment: Solving the `cl` problem likely won't let you install the module. The file being compiled here `py_gpio.c` likely depends on Linux-specific (and maybe Raspberry-Pi specific) operating system support. If you want to try anyways you can try following the instructions here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: Ok, so i checked it, and i installed VC++ when installing VS 2017. So i should have the right version.
For the cl.exe, it is installed, so i modified my Windows Path and i tried to install it again, i got the following error in my output :
`code` c:\program files\python36\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier include : 'io.h' : No such file or directory" `code`