# Where is cl.exe? (MS Build Tools ’13)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I just want the VC++ compiler, since some C++ graphics libraries (I'm planning to use and learn bgfx...) require it for compilation. For this I’ve downloaded and installed [*Ms. Build Tools ’13*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760). However, I can’t find it.

My attempts:

- 1) I’ve ran Windows Command Prompt using the Batch input `cl` and it echoed ***`'cl'`****`is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`*.
- 2) I’ve searched for a file with filename ***`cl`***`.exe` on both `"C:\Programs Files"` and `"C:\Programs Files (x86)"` paths recursively and nothing. There’s no top folder related to MsVC++ or VC++ too, on the disk.

I cannot try to install [Build Tools ’15](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) (nor VS) since the installer downloads at minimum 3 gygabytes and my network isn’t good.

Where can I find the compiler? Otherwise, is there any cross-platform graphics library (at least for Windows and Mac) that doesn’t need MSVC++ (e.g., just G++), please?

Comment: You have to execute a batch file to setup the environment. Look for vcvars32.bat or vcall.bat in the installation directory.

Comment: The Visual Studio installer sets up a number of command shells with the correct path set.  Either use them directly or look at what they setup.  You will find them off your main Start menu.

Comment: You can browse you vc++ installation folder then in something like: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.ex`.

Comment: At least for Visual Studio the C++ compiler can be an optional component which isn't installed by default; and for that case you could open/create a C++-project to trigger download.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953769/visual-studio-doesnt-have-cl-exe?rq=1

Comment: Does the installation appear in _Programs and Features_ (_Add/Remove Programs_)? You could click on your _Windows_ (_Start_) button and start typing "Visual Studio" or "Microsoft Visual Studio" and see if you can get something from what it suggests. However, @HansOlsson seems to be right. From [\[MSDN\]: Microsoft Build Tools 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760): "_... you can use Build Tools 2013 to build **managed** applications. ..._".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Otherwise, is there any cross-platform graphics library (at least for Windows and Mac) that doesn’t need MSVC++

Yes, you should be able to use modern OpenGL in a cross-platform way under Mingw using 
[GLFW](http://www.glfw.org) (since it's a CMAKE compile-it-yourself library) and the excellent [GLAD](http://glad.dav1d.de/) for handling loading of the modern openGL API on windows.

Answer (score 5):

As a commenter mentioned, the Microsoft Build Tools 201x include tools to build managed apps (i.e. .Net apps), *not* native C++ apps. That's the answer to "where is `cl.exe`?" It's not there. It was never there.

That's true for the [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) too, despite what you think and said. You're mixing up *Microsoft Build Tools 2015* and *Visual **C++** 2015 Build Tools*. Note the "C++" there (and the order of some of the words).

The Visual C++ Build Tools are the supported and recommended way by Microsoft to Build visual C++ projects without installing Visual Studio.

If your problem is internet connection get someone else to download it for you, seriously. You're really looking at it the wrong way.

Another alternative is the [*Enterprise WDK*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/using-the-enterprise-wdk). It's "only" 1.9GB.