# Makefile.vc(18) : fatal error U1050: Unable to auto-detect toolchain architecture! If cl.exe is in your PATH rerun nmake with ARCH=<arch>. Stop

Tags: makefile, visual-studio-2017, command-prompt, webp, cl.exe

I'm trying to build `libwebp.dll` for webp, using [these instructions](http://www.kopf.com.br/kaplof/libwebp-dll-binaries-for-windows-download-missing/)  (I downloaded this [source code](https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/libwebp-1.0.0.tar.gz))

However, I'm getting the error:

> Makefile.vc(18) : fatal error U1050: Unable to auto-detect toolchain architecture! If cl.exe is in your PATH rerun nmake with ARCH=. Stop.`

on command `nmake /f Makefile.vc CFG=release-dynamic RTLIBCFG=dynamic OBJDIR=output` in the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2017 (Community Edition).

I don't see file `cl.exe` anywhere in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to install Visual C++. See this post: [Visual studio doesn't have cl.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953769/visual-studio-doesnt-have-cl-exe)

After that I could use this command and it works:

`nmake /f Makefile.vc CFG=release-dynamic RTLIBCFG=dynamic OBJDIR=output ARCH=x64`