# 2020: nvcc fatal : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH

Tags: visual-studio, deep-learning, cuda, nvidia

I'm trying to run StyleGan2 by Nvidia. I have created a new enviroment, I failed this check mandated in the readme file provided.

[image]

In particular, when I run it, I get the error you see in the title of the question. I looked it up, and the solution ostensibly is to add this path to env vars

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin
```

I'm trying to do that, but I don't have `bin` in my `VC` folder! I only have `include` and `lib`, brand new installation of visual studio.

Comment: Are you actually certain you installed the C++ toolchain? https://stackoverflow.com/q/31953769/681865

Comment: @talonmies thanks, I'm trying it now.

Comment: @talonmies it worked, although the path is now different. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @talonmies, the solution is as follows:
Firstly, c++ package doesn't come by default with a clean new installation of VS, you need to select the package.
Secondly, it seems that now the path for cl.exe is here

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\Hostx64\x64
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the full error message was:

> nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH
>
> ...
>
> No CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER could be found.
>
> Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the
> environment variable "CUDACXX" or the CMake cache entry
> CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER to the full path to the compiler, or to the
> compiler name if it is in the PATH.

So I had to do:

```
export CUDACXX="/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.31.31103/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"
```

and it worked.